# How do I mock (request-promise).defaults({ jar: true }) using Jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, request-promise

I am trying to write a test that uses a mock implementation of request-promise with defaults set.

In my code, I require request using
`const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });`

In my test file, I have tried

```
const request = require('request-promise');

jest.mock('request-promise');
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));

// This returns the error 'TypeError: request is not a function'
```

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });

jest.mock('request-promise');
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));

// This returns the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined'
```

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });

jest.mock('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));

// This returns the error 'TypeError: jest.mock(...).defaults is not a function'
```

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });

jest.mock(('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true }));
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));

// This returns the error 'TypeError: "request-promise".defaults is not a function'
```

My function looks like

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });

const getData = async function getData(
  previousRequestResponse,
  uniqueId,
) {

  // Below function carries out some manipulation of previous response
  const body = await getRequestBody(previousRequestResponse);

  const response = await request(method, url, body, headers)
    .then(response => JSON.parse(response.body))
    .catch((err) => {
      Logger.error('Failed');
      Logger.error(`ERROR - ${err.message}`);
      throw err;
    });

  const newResponse = manipulate(response);

  return newResponse;
};
```

I want to mock request, so that response is a stubbed value and I can assert the correct value is returned at the end of the function.

Comment: Hi @Heather, can you further elaborate on what are you trying to achieve? I get that you have in your code something like `request.defaults({ jar: true })`. What are you trying to test?

Comment: @mgarcia Thanks for replying! So, in my code I have a function that uses request to make multiple calls to a 3rd party API.  Each call uses the cookies from the last, hence the need to add the jar.  Thanks for looking @mg When testing this function, I want to mock these calls, using jest.mock so instead of actually calling the 3rd party API, they just return a stub, in this example `someVar`.  I will then assert that when calling my function, I get the expected result based on my stubbed data.  Hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Mmm, maybe you can the calls done with `request-promise` without having to mock the `defaults` call. If you could show the minimal, relevant version of the code you are trying to test I could set a test example.

Comment: I have tried to add some additional info above and an example of my code.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to mock the `request-promise` module you can do it using the [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) method and providing the `factory` parameter.

If you were to test your `getData` method you can create a factory that looks like:

```
jest.mock('request-promise', () => {
    const mock = {
        __esModule: true,
        default: (method, url, body, headers) => Promise.resolve({
            body: JSON.stringify([])
        }),
        defaults: () => mock.default
    };

    return mock;
});
```

With this code, your calls to `request` will always return an object with a `body` property that contains an empty array (as string so that the `JSON.parse` call in the `getData` method can parse it).

**Appendix: Why the attempts you tried so far were not successful**

**Attempt 1**

```
const request = require('request-promise');

jest.mock('request-promise');
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));
```

Here you are calling [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) on the module without a factory parameter. Thus, jest will auto-mock all the module methods and they will all return `undefined` when called.
Hence, when in your code you import the module and call the `defaults` method:

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });
```

the `request` variable results in `undefined`. Later, when you call the `request` method it throws:

> 'TypeError: request is not a function'

**Attempt 2**

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });

jest.mock('request-promise');
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));
```

The same logic of the previous attempt applies here. The `request` variable will be `undefined` and when you try to call the `mockImplementation` method it throws:

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined'

**Attempt 3**

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });

jest.mock('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));
```

Here you are calling the method `defaults` on the returning value of the call to `jest.mock`. As the call to `jest.mock` does not return your mocked version of the `request-promise` module, it does not contain a `defaults` method. So, when you call that method it throws:

> 'TypeError: jest.mock(...).defaults is not a function'

**Attempt 4**

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true });

jest.mock(('request-promise').defaults({ jar: true }));
request.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(someVar)));
```

In this attempt you are trying to call a `defaults` method from the string `request-promise`. Strings have no such method, so calling it throws:

> 'TypeError: "request-promise".defaults is not a function'

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that is super helpful!